# Runtime Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers

Tags: runtime-error, reduce, mern

Basically I am getting the error :
"reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers
at configureStore

My git repository is https://github.com/Bala-Sai-Teja-Singh/error
and the complete error is

```
configureStore.ts:167 Uncaught Error: "reducer" is a required argument, and must be a function or an object of functions that can be passed to combineReducers
    at configureStore (configureStore.ts:167:1)
    at ./src/store.js (store.js:13:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at fn (hot module replacement:62:1)
    at ./src/index.js (productConstant.js:3:1)
    at options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
    at startup:7:1
    at startup:7:1
```

But when I log my reducer in store.js I am getting its type as afunction only please anyone could help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

When using configureStore() you need to provide an object with the key 'reducer', here is the example:

```
const store = configureStore({ reducer: rootReducer })
```

For more information and examples check
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore